# Getting Error while querying to mysql with doobie

Tags: scala, doobie

I have transactor below

```
val transactor: Resource[IO, HikariTransactor[IO]] =
    for {
      ce <- ExecutionContexts.fixedThreadPool[IO](32) // our connect EC
      be <- Blocker[IO] // our blocking EC
      xa <- HikariTransactor.newHikariTransactor[IO](
        "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems",
        "username",
        "password",
        ce, 
        be
      )
    } yield xa
```

I am querying mysql with below code

```
val table = "companies"
  val keyCol = "id"
  val columns = List("address",
                     "city",
                     "companyname",
                     "email",
                     "mobile",
                     "id",
                     "registerdate",
                     "registrationexp")


val queryString =
      s"""SELECT ${columns.mkString(", ")}
          FROM $table WHERE $keyCol = ? """
    log.debug(s"$queryString")
    transactor.use { xa =>
      {
        Query[Int, Company](queryString).option(id).transact(xa)
      }
    }
```

Company is a case class having above column name

But getting below error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.Some to Company
```

where I am doing wrong

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: My guess is that .option gives a Option[Company], thus transact will return a IO[Option[Company]]. Can you try Query[Int, Option[Company]] ?

Comment: Thanks problem is not in that code I have rectified it.